# How to end an emergency call using adb commands on an Android phone

Tags: android, adb

The recommended command is

```
adb shell input keyevent 6
```

But this only works with non-emergency calls. The device doesn't respond to this command during an emergency 911 call.

Any idea how would I go about ending a 911 call using adb commands ?

Comment: "The recommended command is" -- there is no requirement for any particular `adb shell` command to be able to end a call (emergency or otherwise). How a dialer behaves is up to the developers of the dialer.

Comment: This is the native dialer on the android. The command works for non-emergency calls.

Comment: "This is the native dialer on the android" -- there are dozens, perhaps hundreds, of "native dialers" across the tens of thousands of Android device models. "The command works for non-emergency calls" -- for the phone you are testing, perhaps. It may not work for all phones.